# VBA Case sensitive Application.Match

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to get a case sensitive match using Application.Match in Excel VBA.

I have read a bunch of posts that refer to formulas using INDEX and MATCH and EXACT but I need this to work in VBA... 
I have also had no luck using WorksheetFunction.Match Here is the code I need to modify to make it case sensitive. Thanks in advance

```
Sub Validate_Values2()

Dim i As Long, f As Variant

With Worksheets("Company")


    For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
      f = Application.Match(.Cells(i, "M").Value2, Worksheets("Lookups").Columns("U"), 0)
        If IsError(f) Then
            .Cells(i, "M").Interior.ColorIndex = 33
        End If
    Next i
    End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: Use [`Range.Find()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) it has a `MatchCase` setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direct string-to-string comparison in VBA is case sensitive with vbBinaryCompare. Why attempt to bend the wrong worksheet function to your will when VBA has the answer natively with the [Filter function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filter-function)?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Validate_Values3()

    Dim i As Long, f As Long, comps As Variant, lookups As Variant

    With Worksheets("Lookups")
        'skips a header row in Lookups!:U:U
        'creates a zero-based 1-D array 
        lookups = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(2, "U"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp)).Value2)
    End With

    With Worksheets("Company")

        'skips a header row in Company!:M:M
        'creates a one-based 2-D array 
        comps = .Range(.Cells(2, "M"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp)).Value2

        For i = LBound(comps, 1) To UBound(comps, 1)
            'Debug.Print comps(i, 1) & " " & UBound(Filter(lookups, comps(i, 1), True, vbBinaryCompare))

            f = UBound(Filter(lookups, comps(i, 1), True, vbBinaryCompare))

            If f < 0 Then
                'shift down one row to account for skipped header
                .Cells(i + 1, "M").Interior.ColorIndex = 33
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function matchCaseSensitive(lookupV As Variant, lookupA As Variant, Optional MatchType As Variant = 2, _
              Optional LookIn As Variant = xlValues, _
              Optional LookAt As Variant = xlWhole, _
              Optional SearchOrder As Variant = xlByRows, _
              Optional SearchDirection As Variant = xlNext, _
              Optional MatchCase As Variant = True)
 'like Application.WorksheetFunction.match but case sensitive for String in lookupV and Range in lookupA
 On Error GoTo Error
 If VarType(lookupA) < vbArray Then GoTo Error
 If MatchType = 2 Then
  If VarType(lookupV) = vbString And TypeName(lookupA) = "Range" Then
   matchCaseSensitive = lookupA.Find( _
    What:=lookupV, _
    LookIn:=LookIn, _
    LookAt:=LookAt, _
    SearchOrder:=SearchOrder, _
    SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, _
    MatchCase:=MatchCase).Row - lookupA.Row + 1
    Exit Function
  End If
  MatchType = 0
 End If
 matchCaseSensitive = Application.WorksheetFunction.match(lookupV, lookupA, MatchType)
 Exit Function
Error:
 matchCaseSensitive = CVErr(2042)
End Function
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).